# What processes are there to stop carding (spambots)?

Tags: function

as a victim of carding before which resulted in me losing over £1k, I am slightly worried that the Dojo payment terminal on the website looks very susceptible to such an attack.

Are there any tools or configuration settings that will be introduced to prevent this? (e.g. minimum transaction amount/ max transaction amount/ block IPs with multiple card detail attempts/ country blocks etc)

Thanks

I did try a fake card number and the page for payment does not change, which I believe makes the portal extremely vulnerable to a bot which just has to cycle through credit card numbers.